# Dreamweaver CS6: Have two log in users, cannot delete either

Tags: dreamweaver

I am using Dreamweaver CS6 to create a website. I am currently working on a log-in page. For some reason, I have two log in user server behaviors when I added and need only one. It keeps giving the error:

[image]

I can't delete either of them. When I edit one, it creates a new log in user with the edited properties, but the original one is still there. However, I can delete the new created ones. This is what the Server Behavior's box looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end, simply recreating the page worked best.